# Как парсить JSON в массив или обращаться к его элементам?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Вот мой JSON:

```html
{
    "items": [{
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "Bill Gates",
        "age": 43
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name": "Sergey Brin",
        "age": 33
    }, {
        "id" : 3,
        "name": "Larry Page",
        "age": 34
    },{
        "id": 4,
        "name":"dsfsdfs",
        "age":34
    }]
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">   
            $(function () {
                $.getJSON('/test2/obj/data/base.json', function (data) {    
                   // alert(data);
                    
                    for (var key in data['items']) {
                            alert(" "+ key + " "+data[key]);
                            }                      
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Как мне получить массив в JS? Parse не катит, также нужен for для обращения к элементам. Нужно этот JSON загнать в таблицу, и все!

Разобрался! 
stack.js - загружает JSON - генерирует таблицу - отдает ее index.php

```
  $('document').ready(function(){
    loadData();
});

    function loadData() {
        //загружаю  на страницу
        $.getJSON('objects.json', function (data) {
          //  console.log(data);
           var out = '';
            out+='<table class="table table-hover">';
            out+='<thead>';
                out+='<tr>';
                    out+='<th>Формат</th>';
                    out+='<th>Адрес</th>';
                    out+='<th>Завод</th>';
                    out+='<th>№ телефона заведующего</th>';
                    out+='<th>№ городского телефона </th>';
                    out+='<th> ФИО заведующего</th>';
                out+='</tr>';
            out+='</thead>';
            out+='<tbody>';

            for (var key in data){
                out+='<tr>';
                out+='<td>'+data[key]['format']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data[key]['adress']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data[key]['factory']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data[key]['phone1']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data[key]['phone2']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data[key]['fio']+'</td>';
                out+='</tr>';
            }
                out+='</tbody>';
                out+='</table>'; 
            $('#items').html(out);

        })
    }
```

Сам JSON objects.json

```
{
  "101" : {
    "format" : "АЗП-1",
    "adress" : "г. Скидель, ул. Ленина, 78Б",
    "factory" : "2302",
    "phone1" : "8-029-117-17-75",
    "phone2" : "",
    "fio" : "Стокиш Светлана Михайловна"
  },
  "102" : {
    "format" : "АЗП-2",
    "adress" : "г. Скидель, ул. Ленина, 4",
    "factory" : "2303",
    "phone1" : "8-029-327-47-34",
    "phone2" : "",
    "fio" : "Сакович Тамара Анатольевна"
  },
  "103" : {
    "format" : "АЗП-3",
    "adress" : "г. Скидель, ул. Кирова, 3а",
    "factory" : "2304",
    "phone1" : "8-044-585-88-48",
    "phone2" : "",
    "fio" : "Мулярчик Наталья Дмитриевна"
  }
}
```

И index.php

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Торговые объекты");
?>

<head>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css'> 
</head>

<body>   

<div id="items"></div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" async></script>
<script src="js/stack.js" async></script>

</body>

<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` чем не устраивает ?

Comment: у меня не получалось  использовать parse , т.к. была ошибка
       Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод JSON.parse() разбирает строку JSON.
Есть метод JSON.stringify(). Он работает наоборот - преобразует значение JavaScript в строку JSON.

```
$.getJSON('/test2/obj/data/base.json', function (data) {    
    const responseData = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var key in responseData['items']) {
        alert(`Key: $(key), name: $(data[key].name), age: $(data[key].age).`);
    }                      
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! но вот что alert выводит.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

не могу понять почему alert так оформлен. Можете рассказать ?

Comment: JSON.parse(data); не хочет парсить json. Формат в  base.json правильный

Comment: `$.getJSON` самостоятельно парсит json. В шаблонной строке вы используете `data[key]` вместо `responseData['items'][key]` и неправильные скобки(круглые вместо фигурных)